# Mysql Search by day

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, dayofweek

How do I search by day

I have a table with a date field with format: `2012-11-19`  and i wish to SELECT results by day.

My Html: Search by day eg Tuesday

Then Mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = Tuesday
```

And I will get results from Tuesdays only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DAYNAME(date) = 'Tuesday'
```

Check the link [**DAYNAME Function**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname)

Comment: my code is now:<br/>$query1 = "SELECT * FROM $tableName LIMIT $start, $limit WHERE DAYNAME(date_of_draw) = '$day' ORDER BY date_of_draw DESC";<br/> but am getting an error dont where i went wrong

Comment: oh i figured it out, i had placed my LIMIT wrongly, thanks pal

Answer (score 0):

Use [WEEKDAY()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday)

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE weekday(`date`) = 1
```